# How to read/writetwo HashMap objects to file in Java?

Tags: java, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I've been working on a project where I need to write two hash maps to a .dat file in Java. I need to be able to add, remove, and modify an employeeMap hashmap and then write it to a file, and likewise for the other gradeMap HashMap. I don't have any issues adding, removing, or modifying the hashmaps themselves, but I am struggling to write the code to be able to write the objects to a file and read the objects from a file. Here's the class code and main code.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
//class code
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee>, Serializable
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String fname;
    private String lname;
    private int ID;

    /**
     * default constructor for the employee class
     */
    Employee()
    {
        setFname("");
        setLname("");
        setID(0);   
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param ln last name
     * @param fn first name
     * @param id ID number
     */
    Employee(String ln, String fn, int id)
    {
        setFname(fn);
        setLname(ln);
        setID(id);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return first name of the employee
     */
    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param fname first name of the  employoee
     */
    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return last name of the employee
     */
    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param lname last name of the employee
     */
    public void setLname(String lname){
        this.lname = lname;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return ID number
     */
    public int getID(){
        return ID;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param iD id number
     */
    public void setID(int iD) 
    {
        this.ID = iD;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if(this == obj)
            return true;
        else if(obj == null)
            return false;
        else if(obj instanceof Employee)
        {
            Employee o = (Employee) obj;
            return this.fname.equals(o.fname) && this.lname.equals(o.lname) && this.ID == o.ID;
        }
        else
            return false;

    }

    public int hashCode() 
    {
        final int HASH_MULTIPLIER = 29;

        int h = HASH_MULTIPLIER * fname.hashCode() + lname.hashCode();
        h = HASH_MULTIPLIER * h + ((Integer) ID).hashCode();

        return h;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Employee e) 
    {
        if(this.lname.compareTo(e.lname) == 0)
        {
            if(this.fname.compareTo(e.fname) == 0 )
            {
                if(this.ID > e.ID)
                    return 1;
                else if(this.ID == e.ID)
                    return 0;
                else
                    return -1;
            }
        }
        return this.lname.compareTo(e.lname);
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return("Last Name: " + lname + "\nFirst Name: " + fname + "\nID: " + ID);
    }
}
```

Main Code

```
    import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
public class Main {

    private static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException 
    {
        Map <Integer,Employee> employeeMap;
        Map <Employee, Integer> gradeMap;

        File f = new File("Employee.dat");

        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
        if(f.exists())
        {
            try(ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(f)))
            {
                employeeMap = (HashMap<Integer,Employee>) in.readObject();
                gradeMap = (HashMap<Employee,Integer>) in.readObject();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                employeeMap = new HashMap<Integer, Employee>();
                gradeMap = new HashMap<Employee, Integer>();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            employeeMap = new HashMap<Integer, Employee>();
            gradeMap = new HashMap<Employee, Integer>();
        }
        int choice = 0;
        do
        {
            choice = printMenuAndGetChoice();

            switch(choice)
            {
            case 1:
                addEmployee(employeeMap, gradeMap);
                out.writeObject(gradeMap);
                out.close();
                break;
            case 2:
                removeEmployee(employeeMap, gradeMap);
                out.writeObject(employeeMap);
                out.writeObject(gradeMap);
                break;
            case 3:
                modifyEmployee(employeeMap, gradeMap);
                out.writeObject(employeeMap);
                out.writeObject(gradeMap);
                break;
            case 4:
                display(gradeMap);
                break;
            case 5:
                break;
            default:
                    break;
            }

        } while(choice != 5);

    }

    public static int printMenuAndGetChoice()
    {

        int choice = 0;
        System.out.println("1) Add an employee");
        System.out.println("2) Remove an employee");
        System.out.println("3) Modify information for an employee");
        System.out.println("4) Print employees");
        System.out.println("5) Exit");
        System.out.println("Choice: ");
        choice = in.nextInt();

        return choice;
    }

    public static void addEmployee(Map<Integer, Employee> employeeMap, Map<Employee, Integer> gradeMap)
    {
        Employee newEmployee = new Employee();
        System.out.println("Enter the last name for this employee");
        newEmployee.setLname(in.next());
        System.out.println("Enter the first name for this employee");
        newEmployee.setFname(in.next());
        System.out.println("Enter the ID for this employee");
        newEmployee.setID(in.nextInt());

        System.out.println("Enter the work performance value (1 - 5) for this employee");
        int performance = in.nextInt();
        int x = 0;

        Set<Employee> empList = gradeMap.keySet();

        for(Employee e: empList)        
            if(e.equals(newEmployee))
            {
                System.out.println("Employee already exists!\n");
                break;
            }

        int hash = newEmployee.getID() * newEmployee.hashCode();
        employeeMap.put(hash, newEmployee);
        gradeMap.put(newEmployee, performance);
    }
    public static void removeEmployee(Map<Integer, Employee> employeeMap, Map<Employee, Integer> gradeMap)
    {
        System.out.println("\nEnter the ID number of the employee to be removed: ");
        int id = in.nextInt();

        if(!employeeMap.containsKey(id))
            System.out.println("The employee does not exist.\n Please enter another ID");
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Employee removed:" + employeeMap.get(id).getFname() + " " + employeeMap.get(id).getLname() + "\n");
            gradeMap.remove(employeeMap.get(id));
            employeeMap.remove(id);
        }
    }

    public static void modifyEmployee(Map<Integer, Employee> employeeMap, Map<Employee, Integer> gradeMap)
    {
        Set<Employee> empList = gradeMap.keySet();

        System.out.println("\nEnter the ID number of the employee to be removed: ");
        int id = in.nextInt();

        if(employeeMap.containsKey(id) == false)
            System.out.println("The employee does not exist.\n Please enter another ID");
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the work performance value (1 - 5) for this employee");
            int performance = in.nextInt();
            gradeMap.put(employeeMap.get(id), performance);
        }
    }

    public static void display(Map<Employee, Integer> gradeMap)
    {
        Set<Employee> empList = gradeMap.keySet();
        for(Employee e: empList)
            System.out.println(e.toString()+ " " +  "\nPerformance: " + gradeMap.get(e) + "\n");
    }
}
```

I've been referring to my textbook and online lecture notes and I can't seem to figure out the issue. Anyone have any ideas where I might be doing something wrong(I definitely am)? Thanks for the help.

Comment: What's in.readObject()?

Comment: It seems to me that your use of the output stream is inconsistent.  First, you appear to be opening the ObjectOutputStream before you open the ObjectInputStream.  This is probably erasing anything you have previously written.  Next, in your switch block, you seem to close the stream in case 1, but not in 2 or 3.  I believe in cases 1,2,3 you should open the ObjectOutputStream, save the maps, and then close it.  Finally, in case 1, you are only writing the gradeMap, which will case an error when you start up as you first attempt to read the employeeMap which is of a different type.